# Jenkins Builds disappear while in progress

Tags: jenkins

Today I've had 7 different builds completely disappear from Jenkins while running. They don't show in the build history. When I attempt to manually kick off a build for one of these projects, Jenkins will skip the build number for the build that failed and is now missing.

When I monitor the console output of one of these builds in progress, it eventually shows me a 404 screen (see attached).

[image]

I can't seem to find any evidence of these builds ever having been started, other than the skipped build number when I attempt to build the same project again. Restarting Jenkins seems to fix the problem temporarily.

**Edit**:
Per the request of a commenter below, I looked for the folder for the specific job that disappeared in the image above. The folder was there. I ran `tail log` and got the following:

```
# Last 10 lines of /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/dev-deploy-logo-detection-service/builds/154/log
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting opencv-python==4.5.4.60 (from logo-detection-service==0.0.1)
  Downloading opencv_python-4.5.4.60-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60.3 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 60.3/60.3 MB 13.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting numpy<2.0.0,>=1.19.5 (from logo-detection-service==0.0.1)
  Using cached numpy-1.25.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (17.7 MB)
Collecting torch<2.0.0,>=1.10.0 (from logo-detection-service==0.0.1)
```

I know that torch interacts with graphics drivers, so I guess it isn't entirely out of the realm of possibility that the installation crashed the process running the build. I would've at least expected some kind of error message in the log.

**Edit 2**:
I also searched the Jenkins system log for an error related to that build. All I found was this:

```
2023-07-13 18:11:54.839+0000 [id=85002] INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 18:12:10.002+0000 [id=85002] INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 18:12:10.293+0000 [id=85149] INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 18:12:10.917+0000 [id=671]   INFO    c.c.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger$1#run: SCM changes detected in dev-deploy-logo-detection-service. Triggering #154
2023-07-13 18:12:21.971+0000 [id=673]   INFO    c.c.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger$1#run: SCM changes detected in dev-deploy-logo-detection-service. Triggering #154
2023-07-13 18:26:37.321+0000 [id=18]    INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 18:26:37.359+0000 [id=19]    INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 18:26:56.361+0000 [id=105]   INFO    c.c.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger$1#run: SCM changes detected in dev-deploy-logo-detection-service. Triggering #155
2023-07-13 18:26:58.468+0000 [id=104]   INFO    c.c.jenkins.GitHubPushTrigger$1#run: SCM changes detected in dev-deploy-logo-detection-service. Triggering #155
2023-07-13 19:37:39.937+0000 [id=19]    INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 19:37:39.953+0000 [id=18]    INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
2023-07-13 20:16:56.171+0000 [id=19]    INFO    o.j.p.g.w.s.DefaultPushGHEventSubscriber$1#run: Poked dev-deploy-logo-detection-service
```

Comment: Go into your Jenkins home > jobs folder and see if the build folders exist